# Styling related components in ant design

Tags: antd, styled-components, ant-design-pro

I am able to style an antd checkbox component by simply wrapping it with styled.

```
import { Checkbox } from 'antd';
const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`...`
```

However, when I want to render something derivative, like a `Checkbox.Group`,
all of the styling breaks when i use a `StyledCheckbox.Group`

The styled version no longer contains the group property.

Is there a method for overcoming this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a method for overcoming this?

I don't think so. I think you should rather create two styled components sharing common style :

```js
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const commonStyle = css`
  ...
`;

const StyledCheckbox = styled(Checkbox)`
  ${commonStyle}
`;

const StyledCheckboxGroup = styled(Checkbox.Group)`
  ${commonStyle}
`;
```